# What is Amend Commit checkbox in git extension?

Tags: git, git-extensions

What is `Amend Commit` checkbox and what does it do?

[image]

Comment: I have never used Git extensions, but I'm guessing that it just does a `git commit --amend`.  Search for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git ammend merges your changes into your last commit instead of storing it as a new commit. Can be quite handy when you still needed to tweak a little thing you forgot when comitting.

Comment: Note that `git commit --amend` *does* store a new commit, like any other commit. The key is that the new commit's parent is not the current commit, but rather the current commit's *parent*. So when you look at history you won't see your "brother" commit; he's been shoved aside, out of the picture.

Comment: Ah, OK. I didn't know that. Thanks for the clarification!